# "Request method GET not supported" error when trying to get CSS file

Tags: java, html, css, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a JSP file that contains a link to a CSS in `<head>`. However, I'm getting a `HTTP ERROR 405: Request method 'GET' not supported` when I click on that link.

index.jsp:

```
<head>
   <title>The Ultimate Address App</title>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
   <link href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

Here is my directory structure.

```
webapp
   resources
      css
         bootstrap.css
   WEB-INF
      views
         jsp
            index.jsp
```

Config.java:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "com.bpd.addressapp.controllers" })
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getGlobal();

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
   }

   @Bean
   public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
      InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
      viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
      viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/jsp/");
      viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
      return viewResolver;
   }

}
```

I am not using any XML configuration files, so here is the Java version of a `web.xml` file.

```
public class Initializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
      return Arrays.asList(Config.class).toArray(new Class[1]);
   }

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
      return null;
   }

   @Override
   protected String[] getServletMappings() {
     return Arrays.asList("/").toArray(new String[1]);
   }

}
```

In my controller, I have this method:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

   @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String index(Map<String, Object> model) {
      ...
      return "index";
   }

   ...

}
```

I suspect that the controller is causing this problem. When I removed `value = "/"` and then clicked on the link to the CSS file in the HTML source, I was redirected back to the `index.jsp` page.

How can I fix this problem so the `index.jsp` page can be rendered correctly?

Comment: Do other links work?

Comment: if i understand your question correctly, it is not loading the css, when the page is rendered. can you try with <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen, print" />

Comment: also try Arrays.asList("/*").toArray(new String[1]) in getServletMappings

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

And don't forget include taglib at the top of your jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```